Read/Write pipeline in pandas
I'm building a simple pipeline to pull a dataset from a database and write it to a csv so that I can access the data more quickly in the future.
Currently, I have this:
# data loading as a pipeline
# ingests and writes batches of CHUNK_SIZE
CHUNK_SIZE = 10_000
data_loader = pd.read_sql(sql=SQL, con=conn, chunksize=CHUNK_SIZE)
for chunk in tqdm(data_loader, total=chunks) :
    chunk.to_csv("data/raw/statanom.pit_train.csv", mode="a")

It occurs to me that there is a bottle neck in that it is working sequentially when it could begin pulling the next chunk of data while the previous chunk is being written to disk.
Assuming it's possible and recommended, how can I parallelize these tasks? I'd like to initiate the query for the next iteration at the same time the previous chunk is being written to disk.

CSV is an inherently inefficient file format, especially for large data (and also not very safe). You should only use it for rather-small files and debugging. Binary formats are the way to go for production. Besides, parallel IO is not necessary always faster, did you check the actual IO throughput and compared it to the SSD bandwidth? I would be also surprised if the SQL part is fast.

The sql part is not fast, but I'm dumping the entire table so there's not much room for optimization. What would you recommend as a file format?

The file format is dependent of your needs but most mainstream binary formats are better than CSV. You can try parquet for example. See this post for more information. Parquet should support multithreaded reads and maybe also parallel writes (not to mention compression).

Change to e.g. CHUNK_SIZE = 102 And replace the for loop with do.to_csv() from pandas. See also here

@Hermann, can you elaborate? I'm not sure why I would change chunk size to 102. That would pull 102 records at a time from the database.

You can use multiprocessing using the concurrent.futures module in python.
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
CHUNK_SIZE = 10_000

# adding a function to simplify
def write_chunk(chunk, filename):
    chunk.to_csv(filename, mode='a', header=False, index=False)

conn = ...  
SQL = ...  
chunks = ...  

data_loader = pd.read_sql(sql=SQL, con=conn, chunksize=CHUNK_SIZE)

output_file = "data/foo.csv"

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    future_to_chunk = {}
    for chunk in tqdm(data_loader, total=chunks):
        future = executor.submit(write_chunk, chunk, output_file)
        future_to_chunk[future] = chunk
    for future in as_completed(future_to_chunk):
        future.result()

Hope this helps!

This still seems to operate on the data sequentially. I'm wondering if the bottleneck is the database restricting me to one query on the connection.
